How to calculate probability of taking 4 cards of the same rank if you can choose 13 cards of a deck?
I am wondering about a slight modification to this question here:
How to calculate probability of taking 4 cards of the same rank successively?
I came up with the exact same idea. But now how to deal with the fact that you get 13 out of 52 cards and not just 4?
My suggestion, keep the idea from above and account for the number of possibilities:
$$
\binom{13}{4} \times \frac{52}{52} \times \frac{3}{51} \times \frac{2}{50} \times \frac{1}{49} \approx 3.4\%
$$
There is also this post:
What is the probability of getting FOUR OF A KIND in a $13$-card poker game?
Where something similar was asked. Look at the top answer, which also yields $3.4\%$, yet the approach is quite different.

Are you saying that you want $\texttt{exactly} 4$ cards of the same rank  $\texttt{somewhere successively}$ in the $13$ cards drawn  ?

Yes, exactly. The case where you only care about at least having 4 of the same rank (could also be even 2x 4 of the same rank or 3x 4 of the same rank (which is of course very unlikely).
